# Unable to update my google play services

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services

I am making a project where I am using firebase authentication. I made my login activity but when I ran it, it said that the application won't run until Google Play services are not updated.

Following are some changes that I made to my app:gradle file.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.devanshisukhija.sicsrattendance"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'
    //implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.4.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}

apply plugin: "com.google.gms.google-services"
```

But I am still getting the following error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
>
> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 11.4.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove this

> apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

because you already have provided

> apply plugin: "com.google.gms.google-services"

so there is no need of applying gms.google.services plugin.
and also add

> classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

in project level build file.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: got it, had that in two different places, removed it both. thanks a ton.

Comment: pleasure please upvote the answer for appreciation. thanks

Answer (score 0):

delete the line in build gradle

```
 apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

"com.android.application" package already has 'com.google.gms.google-services'  package.

Comment: remove  implementation 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0' also